# Mapstruct choose between two Named Mapper methods

Tags: mapstruct

I'm trying to add a different mapper method with the same signature

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = TechnologyMapper.class)
public interface VersionMapper {

    VersionMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(VersionMapper.class);

    @Named("Normal")
    VersionDTO versionToVersionDto(Version version, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    @Named("IgnoreTechnology")
    @Mapping(target = "technology", ignore = true)
    VersionDTO versionToVersionDtoIgnoreTechnology(Version version, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);
```

In the official documentation it shows an example where a another mapper is used to choose between the two. However in my code I use this mapper directly:

```
versionMapper.versionToVersionDtoIgnoreTechnology(version, new CycleAvoidingMappingContext());
```

So How Can I choose between the two?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Named` annotations is meant to signal to other usages of the methods within MapStruct.

When you use it directly it is entirely up to you to decide which method you need to invoke. Only you know the context if your direct invocation and whether you need the technology or not in your mapped `VersionDTO`

Comment: Then Why I get Error:java: Ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping collection element to com.derbyware.devroad.dto.mapper.VersionMapper.versionToVersionDto(),  com.derbyware.devroad.dto.mapper.VersionMapper.versionToVersionDtoIgnoreTechnology(). When I compile the code

Comment: Because you have some mapper that has a collection of versions. You'll need to share more code. Your original question didn't mention the error. That error changes the question completely